# Will a parallel diode across 24Vdc line be effective for relay coil surge relief?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, surge-protection, switching-transients

In our factory, a controller malfunctions many times.

I think, it's becuase of relay coil open surge (24Vdc line, Coil 350mA per each).

So, I put the schottky diode across the DC24V Line in parallel.

Will it be effective for coil surge relief?

at first, I thought so.
but, now, I can't explain the mechanism.

Because, If diode is turn on for surge relief, 24V line should be about -1V.

it's impossible.

I don't know but, now, the controller don't malfunction.

I put only many ferrite cores at AC Powers and DC lines and Diode at 24V dc line.

What would be the most effective mothod among them?
(Ferrite cores or Diode) [image: will a Diode be effective for surge relief?]

Comment: Can you place it across the coil in the relay instead?

Answer (score 1):

Generally a "flyback diode" goes around the MC coil. Not before the switch.

You SMPS should be able to handle the switch off. Its the MC coil that needs the help of the diode.

Beyond this, you will need to give more information like part numbers.

[image]

[Wikipedia article for a flyback diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode)

Comment: Thanks. I know the the right position of diode. But. I can't put many diodes now. So. I put diode at 24vdc line. Is it also effective?

Comment: No. You can confirm this yourself since you have an oscilloscope.

Answer (score 1):

With a DC voltage applied across an inductor, energy would be stored in its magnetic field.

With the DC voltage removed, the magnetic field would collapse and energy would be returned to the source through an arc across the open contact, caused by a high reverse voltage induced across the inductor. The direction of induced current would be the same as that of the applied current.

The arcing could damage the switching contact or transistor as the case may be. It could also cause electromagnetic interference.

The solution would be to use a flyback diode (also referred to as freewheeling diode), connected directly across the inductor, to short-circuit the induced voltage.

Connecting the flyback diode before the contact would serve no purpose as  arcing  would prevail. Should the flyback diode be located at the power supply terminals, the effect of electromagnetic interference could be more severe, on account of the longer path taken by the induced current.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a varistor parallel to the coil. It changes it's resistance based on the back EMF voltage and prevents current spikes.

More information: https://product.tdk.com/de/techlibrary/applicationnote/repeat-surge_varistor_ctvs.html

Comment: Thanks. I know the the right position of diode. But. I can't put many diodes now. So. I put diode at 24vdc line. Is it also effective?